# Changing axis type in ZedGraph

Tags: c#, zedgraph

I have a data of time of consecutive heart beats (in milliseconds) and I'm trying to make a dynamic chart of them. So on XAxis I have XDate variable increased by `.AddMilliseconds(heart_beat_time)` and on YAxis `heart_beat_time`.

When I use `AxisType.Date` it's pretty good. I can change `Min`, `Max` and other related values, but when I change to `AxisType.DateAsOrdinal` I can not see points nor labels. During some debugging it has showed up that Zedgraph does paint the points and labels, but there are very large gaps between consecutive ones.

How can I control `DateAsOrdinal` Min, Max, MajorStep and so on? There is an answer [Format DateAsOrdinal xAxis labels in ZedGraph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4952358/format-dateasordinal-xaxis-labels-in-zedgraph) but it doesn't work for me.

There are two reasons I want to make it work:

1. Ordinal seems to be faster (as I got nearly 100k points)
2. With `AxisType.Date` when I scroll chart automatically it's not showing labels under ticks

My code:

```
myPane.XAxis.Type = AxisType.DateAsOrdinal;
myPane.XAxis.Scale.MajorStepAuto = false;
myPane.XAxis.Scale.MinorStepAuto = false;
myPane.XAxis.Scale.MajorUnit = DateUnit.Minute;
myPane.XAxis.Scale.MinorUnit = DateUnit.Minute;
myPane.XAxis.Scale.Format = "HH:mm:ss";
myPane.XAxis.Scale.Min = Min;
myPane.XAxis.Scale.Max = Max;
myPane.XAxis.Scale.MinorStep = minor;
myPane.XAxis.Scale.MajorStep = major;
myPane.XAxis.Scale.BaseTic = new XDate(1999, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0);
myPane.YAxis.Scale.Min = min_rr;
myPane.YAxis.Scale.Max = max_rr;
```

where

```
int min_rr = 100;
int max_rr = 2500;
XDate Min = new XDate(1999, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0);
XDate Max = new XDate(1999, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0);
int minor = 5;
int major = 10;
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem (no graph or labels on XAxis) when using `AxisType.DateAsOrdinal`.

I solved by omitting the code lines `myPane.XAxis.Scale.Min=???` and `Max=???`.
This gives me a nice graph without gaps.

However now I have problems with the `MousePositionValues` function in my `MouseMoveEvent`.

Comment: **Sorry for 2 in line - time limit :/**

`DateAsOrdinal` keeps number of points on screen not period of time according to `Min` and `Max`

So you got to set `Min=0` and `Max = numberOfPoints`. The same is with `MajorStep` and `MinorStep` - it's number of points between tics.

I think it may cause a problem if you don't know what data you are putting into chart - it can become unreadable because of scale.